# Как правильно сделать глобальный объект?

Tags: python, ооп

Есть некий класс в модуле aaa.py В модуле bbb.py на его основе создаётся объект. Есть модули ccc.py и ddd.py содержащие классы обращающиеся к этому объекту. Как правильно объявить объект, чтобы он был доступен для них? Сейчас у меня просто передаётся ссылка на него в вызове метода класса, но мне это не нравится.

Идеи у меня есть, но хотелось бы послушать мнение других.

Comment: И чем это Вам не нравится? Мест, куда можно приткнуть переменную, содержащую объект, много. Вопрос, станет ли программа понятней?
Например модуль aaa или созданный в нём класс.

     # bbb.py
     import aaa
     aaa.a = aaa.aaaclass()
     aaa.aaaclass.a = aaa.aaaclass()
     # main
     import aaa
     import bbb
     import ccc
     import ddd

Comment: Дело в том, что появился модуль eee. содержащий классы, которые вызываются и ccc и ddd, и им тоже нужны методы этого обьекта (именно объекта, а не класса). Тут я задумался: А может я делаю что-то не так? Ибо этот объект внезапно нужен по всей программе, а классы передают его друг другу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я обычно в таких случаях создаю модуль в котором создаю нужные мне объекты, и потом импортирую его куда надо:

```
# module a
class A:
  pass

obj_a = A()
```

потом в других модулях:

```
# module b
from a import obj_a
...
```

Таким образом получается что создаётся одни объект obj_a для всей программы.

Comment: Т.е.

    # module c
    from a import obj_a
    ...

не сделает ещё один объект (локальный для c), а импортирует тот же?
Нда, значит я плохо читал про импорт.

Comment: нет, не сделает. Получится что то вроде шаблона одиночка (singletone)

Comment: Я вот синглтон и собирался делать - вручную. Что ж, спасибо.